# Angular HttpErrorResponse in view.html

Tags: angular, http, status

I have a little probleme, I don't know, how can I pass an error message in my view.html when the user compose a wrong password.

***Question is resolved***

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   error : string;
   loginUserData = {}
   constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
   ngOnInit() {
   }
   loginUser(){
      this.auth.loginUser(this.loginUserData).subscribe(
       res => {
         localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
         this.router.navigate(['/special']);
       },
       err => {
           if( err instanceof HttpErrorResponse ) {
               if (err.status === 500) {
                   this.error = errLogin.error.message;
               }
           }
       }
       )
   }
}
```

**login.component.html**

```
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="mb-0">Login</h3> {{ error }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable name error

```
error : string;
```

and then assign the value like this,

```
loginUser(){
      this.auth.loginUser(this.loginUserData).subscribe(
       res => {
         localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
         this.router.navigate(['/special']);
       },
       err => {
           if( err instanceof HttpErrorResponse ) {
               if (err.status === 500) {
                   this.error = err.status
               }
           }
       }
       )
   }
```

and use in the component as,

```
<div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="mb-0">Login</h3> {{ error }}
</div>
```

Comment: One question again, if I have an errorof wrong password, In my console browser I have information about this error, I don't want dispaly this message error in console. How can I desactivate this meesage.

Comment: use ngIf for conditional checking

Comment: Non, In Google chrome we have the console, and every times if I put bad request in login form I have in console an error message. In angular does existe the method for desactive this message  n console of browser. Thanks again